# build fail with replace get-login-password

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, command-line-interface, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to update this line to work on CLI v2 and can't see where I'm failing.
From

```
sh "eval \$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)"
```

To

```
sh "aws ecr get-login-password --no-include-email --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ************.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

The build fails at this point every time and I've tried a number of variations of the same to no avail.

Comment: Can you try with `sh -c "aws <and-the-rest"`?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it turns out that the pre prod image I was using to build from was still using CLI v1 which is why it was failing my argument.